# SQLAlchemy unique check on postgresql insert scalability

Tags: python, database, postgresql, orm, sqlalchemy

Can someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong?

All of the below works as required, but I'm running into scalability issues -

> ```
> On the first run i fetched ~70,000 rows into a blank table in ~2-3 s
>
> On the 2nd run i fetched ~80,000 rows into the same table in ~5 min
>
> On the 3rd run i fetched ~50,000 rows into the same table in ~30 min    
>
> On the 4th run i fetched ~120,000 rows into the same table in ~1 hr    
>
> On the 5th run i fetched ~100,000 rows into the same table in ~2 hr
> ```

Each time i run the code, I see a steady ~600KB/s traffic between the client & the db while this activity finishes

So as you see, the hash check across all those columns does not seem to scale well at all

**What is my code trying to accomplish?**

I need to add daily stock data into a postgres database. The data is updated at source only once a day & the API response is as follows -

```
{'instrument_token': '210011653'
'exchange_token': '820358'
'tradingsymbol': 'COLG17MAY1020.00PE'
'name': ''
'last_price': 0.0
'expiry': '2017-05-25'
'strike': 1020.0
'tick_size': 0.05
'lot_size': 700
'instrument_type': 'PE'
'segment': 'BFO-OPT'
'exchange': 'BFO'}
```

The items in the response & the row count changes every day
On a given day, I see i can fetch between 50,000 - 120,000 rows in a single response (i.e approx 20-30 MB of csv data). Sending the request fetches the same data for a given day.

So the core problem is - **I want to avoid adding the same row twice to the db in case the data is fetched multiple times in the same day.**

**What have I tried so far -**

I'm a db newbie, my thought process was to autoincrement an id & add a data_date column, so my schema looks like this -

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS instruments (
    id                  bigserial,
    data_date           date NOT NULL,
    instrument_token    integer NOT NULL,
    exchange_token      integer NOT NULL,
    tradingsymbol       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    name                varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    last_price          numeric(15,2) NOT NULL,
    expiry              date,
    strike              numeric(15,2),
    tick_size           numeric,
    lot_size            integer,
    instrument_type     varchar(10),
    segment             varchar(20),
    exchange            varchar(10),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
    );
```

I've built a class like so -

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, mapper, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Numeric, String, MetaData, Table, ForeignKey, DateTime, union
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

engine = create_engine('postgresql://blah')
Base = declarative_base(engine)

def _unique(session, cls, hashfunc, queryfunc, constructor, arg, kw):
    cache = getattr(session, '_unique_cache', None)
    if cache is None:
        session._unique_cache = cache = {}

    key = (cls, hashfunc(*arg, **kw))
    if key in cache:
        return cache[key]
    else:
        with session.no_autoflush:
            q = session.query(cls)
            q = queryfunc(q, *arg, **kw)
            obj = q.first()
            if not obj:
                obj = constructor(*arg, **kw)
                session.add(obj)
        cache[key] = obj
        return obj

class UniqueMixin(object):
    @classmethod
    def unique_hash(cls, *arg, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def unique_filter(cls, query, *arg, **kw):
        raise NotImplementedError()

    @classmethod
    def as_unique(cls, session, *arg, **kw):
        return _unique(
                    session,
                    cls,
                    cls.unique_hash,
                    cls.unique_filter,
                    cls,
                    arg, kw
               )

class Instrument(UniqueMixin, Base):

        __tablename__ = 'instruments'
        __table_args__ = {'autoload':True}
        __table__ = Table('instruments', Base.metadata,
            Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
            Column('data_date', String),
            Column('instrument_token', Integer),
            Column('exchange_token', Integer),
            Column('tradingsymbol', String),
            Column('name', String),
            Column('last_price', Numeric),
            Column('expiry', Integer),
            Column('strike', Numeric),
            Column('tick_size', Numeric),
            Column('lot_size', Integer),
            Column('instrument_type', String),
            Column('segment', String),
            Column('exchange', String))


        @classmethod
        def unique_hash(cls, data_date, instrument_token, exchange_token, tradingsymbol, name, last_price, expiry, strike, tick_size, lot_size, instrument_type, segment, exchange):
            return data_date, instrument_token, exchange_token, tradingsymbol, name, last_price, expiry, strike, tick_size, lot_size, instrument_type, segment, exchange
        @classmethod
        def unique_filter(cls, query, data_date, instrument_token, exchange_token, tradingsymbol, name, last_price, expiry, strike, tick_size, lot_size, instrument_type, segment, exchange):
            return query.filter(Instrument.data_date == data_date, Instrument.instrument_token == instrument_token, Instrument.exchange_token == exchange_token, Instrument.tradingsymbol == tradingsymbol, Instrument.name == name, Instrument.last_price == last_price, Instrument.expiry == expiry, Instrument.strike == strike, Instrument.tick_size == tick_size, Instrument.lot_size == lot_size, Instrument.instrument_type == instrument_type, Instrument.segment == segment, Instrument.exchange == exchange)



        def __init__(self, data_date, instrument_token, exchange_token, tradingsymbol, name, last_price, expiry, strike, tick_size, lot_size, instrument_type, segment, exchange):

            self.data_date = data_date
            self.instrument_token = instrument_token
            self.exchange_token = exchange_token
            self.tradingsymbol = tradingsymbol
            self.name = name
            self.last_price = last_price
            self.expiry = expiry
            self.strike = strike
            self.tick_size = tick_size
            self.lot_size = lot_size
            self.instrument_type = instrument_type
            self.segment = segment
            self.exchange = exchange

        def __repr__(self):
            return "<Instruments - '%s': '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s' - '%s'>" % (
                                                                                                                                        self.id, 
                                                                                                                                        self.data_date, 
                                                                                                                                        self.instrument_token, 
                                                                                                                                        self.exchange_token, 
                                                                                                                                        self.tradingsymbol, 
                                                                                                                                        self.name, 
                                                                                                                                        self.last_price, 
                                                                                                                                        self.expiry, 
                                                                                                                                        self.strike, 
                                                                                                                                        self.tick_size, 
                                                                                                                                        self.lot_size, 
                                                                                                                                        self.instrument_type, 
                                                                                                                                        self.segment, 
                                                                                                                                        self.exchange
                                                                                                                                        )
```

The code to insert the data looks like this -

```
    for instrument in response:
        #print(instrument)
        if instrument['expiry'] == '' :
            instrument['expiry'] = null()
        market_instrument = Instrument.as_unique(self.session, 
                                                    data_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat(), 
                                                    instrument_token =  instrument['instrument_token'], 
                                                    exchange_token =    instrument['exchange_token'], 
                                                    tradingsymbol = instrument['tradingsymbol'], 
                                                    name =  instrument['name'], 
                                                    last_price =    instrument['last_price'], 
                                                    expiry =    instrument['expiry'], 
                                                    strike =    instrument['strike'],
                                                    tick_size = instrument['tick_size'],
                                                    lot_size =  instrument['lot_size'], 
                                                    instrument_type =   instrument['instrument_type'], 
                                                    segment =   instrument['segment'], 
                                                    exchange = instrument['exchange'], 
                                                    )
        self.session.add(market_instrument)
    self.session.commit()
```

**Options I am considering**

What do you think is best?

**Option 1**
No longer use as_unique(

Create one more data_update_date table (data_date(primary), status(boolean)) which is updated at the end of a successful daily insert

Check data_update_date for today's date, & skip add for the entire block if it exists

However this option does not help me learn if there was another mistake in my as_unique functions that needs to be corrected

**Option 2**
Setup new db with powa & profile

Find & fix bottlenecks

i am using the official postgres docker image, i ran into a dead end extending the debian base with hypopg & other required extensions

Looks like centos will be much simpler, so i'm creating a new dockerfile to do this

However, since i'm a total newbie with postgresql & sqlalchemy i also need your opinion on whether my code has some obvious issues

**Option 3**
hash only a few columns

i could hash just the first 3, excluding id

however i dont know how to do this

just reducing the hash classdef parameters causes the number of parameters to be less than defined in the class, so the insert fails

**Option 4**

I'm not married to either postgresql or sqlalchemy

Should i be using a non ORM method instead?

Or, should i be using something other than a db to store this kind of data

I'm running this on an m2.large instance on AWS, which should have the right kind of performance, so maybe I am using the wrong method to store the data
If this is the situation during insert, multiple threads while doing technical analysis will be simply unusable...

Should I be using something like hadoop instead?

also, an obvious drawback in this option is another learning curve to scale for hadoop...

Comment: Try profiling and see where the bottleneck is. Just a guess: your cache gets so big that it starts writing to disk and reading from it.

Comment: plumSemPy thanks yes am integrating powa. I updated option 2 in my question for this

Comment: You need to let the DB handle uniqueness (via a `UNIQUE` constraint or index).

Comment: univerio unique would not work as desired since it would apply to a single column

Comment: sqlalchemy at least allows for unique tuples

Comment: You can have multi column unique constraints in Postgresql, and SQLAlchemy lets you define them: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint. You probably don't need to make the rows unique over each and every column. Try and identify some key columns. When done, you can also take advantage of the new [`ON CONFLICT` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) when inserting.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you're scanning the entire table for each row you're inserting (The `as_unique()` class method) that does not happen to be in your cache. That does not scale well at all, especially if you happen to use different session instances (lost cache) between batches. You've not presented that part of your code though, so impossible to say. There's the `self.session`, but is it a thread local session or what?

Comment: `code  class DB(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.metadata = Base.metadata
    
    def session(self):

        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

        self.session = self.Session()

        return self.session `

Comment: Ilja Everilä I use this in my client like this -
        `self.db = DB()
         self.session = self.db.session()`

Answer (score 0):

I ran some [db profiling on the bulk insert operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EaN5.png)

The cache hit ratio is 100%

I do not see any disk io

Sorry i can't post more than 2 links right now, so i can't show you the charts for the hit ratio & disk hits, so you'll just have take my word for it :)

The as_unique method basically works using an extremely inefficient method which hits the db with a crazy large # of queries. If anything, I guess this just served as a good benchmark for this server build+config, that leaves me very satisfied with it's performance for cache friendly workloads

As pointed out by hints from various responses, the bottleneck lies in the schema as well as the way the insert is implemented in the code

I fixed the problem like this -

**1. Add a multi-column unique index**

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX market_daily_uq_idx ON instruments (
data_date, 
instrument_token, 
exchange_token, 
tradingsymbol, 
instrument_type, 
segment, 
exchange
);
```

**2. Use .on_conflict_do_nothing()**

```
                statement = insert(Instrument).values( 
                                    data_date = datetime.date.today().isoformat(), 
                                    instrument_token =  instrument['instrument_token'], 
                                    exchange_token =    instrument['exchange_token'], 
                                    tradingsymbol = instrument['tradingsymbol'], 
                                    name =  instrument['name'], 
                                    last_price =    instrument['last_price'], 
                                    expiry =    instrument['expiry'], 
                                    strike =    instrument['strike'],
                                    tick_size = instrument['tick_size'],
                                    lot_size =  instrument['lot_size'], 
                                    instrument_type =   instrument['instrument_type'], 
                                    segment =   instrument['segment'], 
                                    exchange = instrument['exchange'], 
                                    ).on_conflict_do_nothing()


            self.session.execute(statement)
        self.session.commit()
```

This works very well &  [things are much faster now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq6CK.png), thereby solving the core issue

Thank you all very much for all the help, hints & advice!